# How to remove hyphens from string, only when the hyphen has got an alphabet character in neighbor in PHP?

Tags: php

I got this string:

- Joh-na-tan Doe ar-ri-ved.

And I would like get this:

- Johnatan Doe arrived.

I would like to do it in PHP.

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches `letter-letter` and replaces it with the letters.

Comment: See the `preg_replace()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of Barmar's suggestion:

```
$outputString = preg_replace( '/([a-z])-([a-z])/gi', "$1$2", $inputString );
```